# Why a Custom Dependency Property is not Showing in User Control's intellisense?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I created a User Control and in code behind, I added the following DP. When I switch to XAML and try to type the name of the property next to the UserControl tag, for example "Test", it doesn't show up. I wonder what could be missing here.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(String), typeof(UserControl1));
```

Answer (score 3):

You also need to implement the [CLR Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist) for that property:

```
public string Test
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
}
```